# AdonisJS request.post() is empty

Tags: javascript

when the `autoProcess: true` inside `bodyParser.js`, and I didn't put ant routes inside `processManually`. The `request.post()` working fine and showing all the body data from the client.

but when I put the route into `processManually`, the `request.post()` is showing empty object.

The reason why I need to put a routes into `processManually` is because I need to upload the image file into AWS S3

**Only Work if the route is `processManually`**

```
console.log(request.post()) // empty object

request.multipart.file('place[thumbnail[]]', {
  type: ['image'],
  size: '3mb',
}, async (file) => {

})
await request.multipart.process()
```

Comment: Could you provide more information. Can you show us the route function? I only see console.log and I need to see where request was constructed. Will update my answer once you add a bit more code.

Comment: @DallasBaker here
```
// routes.js
Route.post('/places', 'PlaceController.store')

// PlaceController.js
async store({ request, response }) {
  console.log(request.post())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// For multiple files use the keyword *request*.**files**

I don't have experience with the framework, but checking the docs, it appears that they automatically extract the data, you just need to reference it using request.files!

```
import Route from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route'
import Application from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Application'


Route.post('gallery', async ({ request }) => {
  const images = request.files('images')
  for (let image of images) {
    await s3.upload({
      Key: $key,
      Bucket: 's3-bucket-name',
      Body: fs.createReadStream(image.tmpPath) // or pass image
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: why not using Drive ? a libs that came in with adonisjs

Comment: You said you wanted to upload to AWS?

Comment: yes but using the Drive from adonis,

const Drive = use('Drive')

await Drive.disk('s3').put(filePath, fs.createReadStream(image.tmpPath))

Comment: solved, I use your algorithm and change a little bit of code

for (let image of files._files) {
      let filePath
      const fileName = `${new Date().getTime()}_${Common.uuid()}`
      filePath = `img/places/${fileName}.${image.extname}`

      await Drive.disk('s3').put(filePath, fs.createReadStream(image.tmpPath))
    }

Comment: Great! I am happy that you were able to get it working, Cheers!